# Looking for a book about mathematical proof of technical analysis in trading stocks!

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-analysis, economics

I am looking for a book which contents mathematical proof of technical analysis in trading stocks! I have read a lot about techniques in trading stocks, but never that they prove it. I am really thankful if you can guide me or list some books here! Thank you so much!

Comment: What would a proof look like?  Usually the people who advocate one style or other cite track records, or (similarly) do an analysis of historical data.  But neither of those constitute mathematical proof.

Comment: so, you mean they are just a statistics and prediction? thank you!